# A ruby program that takes a name input from user and confirms it. I am not fully being able to code it. Help required

Tags: ruby

What can be an appropriate code for this ? 
I tried using the name = gets.chomp and following it with a "IS IT CORRECT"-esque question. Followed it with a if-else construct but its not working apparently.
Thanks

Comment: "not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, what does "not working apparently" mean? Does it work or not?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough error details. I am new to StackOverflow so I will learn to provide more details as I learn more ! @JörgWMittag  !    But Kostas Stamos has solved the problem I was facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error did you get? This should be quite simple.

```
puts "Enter name"
name = gets.chomp
puts "Is #{name} correct?"
confirm = gets.chomp
if confirm == 'y'
  puts "Your name is #{name}"
else
  puts "Your name is not #{name}"
end
```

Look also at the examples here: http://www.evc-cit.info/cit020/beginning-programming/chp_02/conditionals.html

Comment: Maybe write `puts "Is #{name} correct?"`

Comment: Thank you Kostas Stamos !            I didnt add that '#{name} part and also didnt put ".chomp" in the confirming part !